# Jquery - Submit a form using enter key

Tags: jquery, html

How can I submit a form using Enter key. without having a submit button?

I tested the below code but it does not working.

```
$("input").bind("keydown", function(event) {
   console.log('came');
   var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : (event.which ? event.which : event.charCode));
   if (keycode == 13) { // keycode for enter key
     document.getElementById('submitButton').click();
     // $('#frmAddPurchaseord').submit();
     return false;
     } else  {
     return true;
     }
    }); 
 <form name="frmAddPurchaseord" id="frmAddPurchaseord" action="" method="post">
   //Submit button
  <input id="submitButton" type="image" name="submit"  src="<?=$gCommonImagePath?>btn_save.png" />
 </form>
```

Please suggest me!

Comment: In the question you say, you don't have a submit button, but in the sample code you do have a submit button!

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused with this question.
Usually a form will get submitted on pressing enter key while any input element inside the form tag has focus(except `textarea`). I think that is default form behavior. You really don't need to do any javascript for that. You are probably in some other special case. Can u clarify?

Comment: @rineez) Usually a form will not get submit on pressing enter key I think.. my form will have submit button also.I need to submit my form while pressing enter key

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Keep it simple:**

```
<form name="frmAddPurchaseord" id="frmAddPurchaseord" action="" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="name" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13) {this.submit();}" />
</form>
```

**Using jquery:**

```
$("input").keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#frmAddPurchaseord").submit();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @AlphaMale-I have another one problem.. while I use the enter key form value cannot be stored in db but when I use save button(click) value has been stored in db .. got it

Comment: @KarthickV Can you update your current code. including php part.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to submit the form on every enter key you can bind the event to the document object, you can use `which` property of jQuery `event` object which is cross-browser:

```
$(document).on("keyup", function(event) {
   if (event.which == 13) { 
     $('form').submit();
     event.preventDefault()
   } 
});
```

If no you can try:

```
$('input').on("keyup", function(event) {
   if (event.which == 13) { 
     $('form').submit();
     event.preventDefault()
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$("#frmAddPurchaseord").submit(); /* the id of the form */
```

**jQuery:**

```
 $("input").bind("keydown", function(event) {
      console.log('came');
      var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : (event.which ? event.which : event.charCode));
      if (keycode == 13) { // keycode for enter key
         document.getElementById('buttonId').click();
              $("#frmAddPurchaseord").submit();
         return false;
      } else  {
         return true;
      }
});
```

Comment: I tried it does not working:) even console.log also is not working

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("input").keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#frmAddPurchaseord").submit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name="frmAddPurchaseord" id="frmAddPurchaseord" action="" method="post" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13) {this.submit();}" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zxrCg/)

```
 <form name="frmAddPurchaseord" id="frmAddPurchaseord" action="" method="post">
    <input id="submitButton" type="text" name="submit"  src="<?=$gCommonImagePath?>btn_save.png" />

 </form>
```

jquery `.submit()`

```
$('#frmAddPurchaseord').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($('#submitButton').val());

});
```